# How does this zsh completion style for environment variables work?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I can across the following zstyle setting in a popular shared zsh configuration:

```
# Environment Variables
zstyle ':completion::*:(-command-|export):*' fake-parameters ${${${_comps[(I)-value-*]#*,}%%,*}:#-*-}
```

Source: **sorin-ionescu/prezto** [/modules/completion/init.zsh](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/c9c716e9c11938a1aff2f30230d4dc1da38dc564/modules/completion/init.zsh#L131-L132)

My questions:

1. What does this accomplish? Without using this line (with mostly default zstyle settings) I still get completion for environment variable names when I type `$<Tab>`. There must be some other functionality this affords.
2. How does this work?  According to the manpages, the `fake-parameters` style is used supply the completion system "names of parameters that might not yet be set but should be completed nonetheless". I've also discovered that `_comps[xyz]` is a way to look up the completion function for a particular command `xyz`. I cannot understand the remaining syntax.